# Java PHP Extension is not working

Tags: java, php, php-extension

I have a problem in calling a Java application in my PHP code.

1) I've changed the php.ini file, as the phpinfo() shows:

[image: php_java description in phpinfo()]

And that's the php code, that calls a java class I made for testing.

```
<?php
    $javaPHP = new Java('TesteJP');
    $javaPHP->set("TEST");
    echo "Java Method = " . $javaPHP->get();
?>
```

But when i call this file on browser, it returns the error **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. And when I access the event viewer on server, i've found this error:

```
Faulting application Apache.exe version 2.0.58.200, faulting module
unknown, version 0.0.0.0, fault address 0x01495b58.
```

The print screen of this error is below:

[image: Apache Application error on Event Viewer]

Thank's!

**Update:**
At some moments I try to access de PHP application, it returns an error:

```
Fatal error: java() [<a href='function.java'>function.java</a>]: Unable to
 create Java Virtual Machine in H:\Desenvolvimento\sites\abra3\bol.php on 
line 181
```

Comment: what about error_log?

Comment: I`ve checked the Apache`s log error and I have not found any error messages about this.

Comment: What is line 181 in bol.php?

Comment: @Ishmael Sorry, I forgot and get another php file, but code file above the error is in line 2. in the `new Java()`. The line 181 in bol.php is the same thing.